# Pass pgSetting req parameter in Postgraphile Query using graphiql

Tags: graphiql, postgraphile

Hello I am new to postgraphile, I would like to test adding a new attribute `user.email` to pgSettings on every request. I don't want to use jwt for now.

Here is my `.postgraphilerc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  options: {
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    schema: ['app_public', 'public', 'app_hidden'],
    port: 5433,
    appendPlugins:
      'postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter,postgraphile-plugin-nested-mutations,@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector,@graphile-contrib/pg-many-to-many',
    watch: true,
    dynamicJson: true,
    enhanceGraphiql: true,
    extendedErrors: 'hint,detail,errcode',
    graphileBuildOptions: {
    },
    ignoreRBAC: false,
    showErrorStack: 'json',
    legacyRelations: 'omit',
    pgDefaultRole: 'database_visitor',
    pgSettings: async req => (
      {
        'user.email': req?.session?.passport?.user ?? 'not@logged.user',
      }),
  },
};
```

I would like to test a simple query using graphiql. Where can pass the req object in the graphical interface ?

Here is my query

```
query Users {
  appUsers {
    nodes {
      email
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Should I write something in the headers section ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing parameters in the headers.

```js
pgSettings: async function (req) {
      return (
        {
          'user.email': req.headers["user-email"] || 'not@logged.user',
        });
    }
```

In graphiql in the `request headers` box

```json
{
"user-email":"first@email.com" 
}
```

Let me know if there are better practices

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert either, but you can access that same "user.email" variable in postgres through the current_setting like this

`create function function_x() returns text as $$ select current_setting('user.email', true)::text; $$ language sql stable;`

Then in graphiql you execute the function_x